# Mobile: Accessing/sharing/modifying content/elements in other apps

Tags: android, iphone, macos, mobile, browser-extension

Today in browsers, various mechanisms exist to access and modify a web page.  These can be implemented normally via extensions who employ various DOM access technologies such as Mutation Observers. This feature, for example, allows an extension to detect the life-cycles of DOM elements and augment them or even insert its own DOM elements at appropriate times and locations.

In mobile, I'm aware of Lastpass that employs a technique somewhat akin to this, where it is able to detect userid and password fields and auto-fill them. It seems they use mobile accessibility features to accomplish this (at least in iOS). I'm sure there are more apps that can do similar things.

However, I'd like to push this further, and be able to read the content/elements of another app ('serving app') at the very least and manipulate it and display it in our own app ('client app') much like the extension example above. A simple example can be an app that streams content, where we want to read this stream, filter, augment it, and display it in our own app. Even better, be able to augment it in the app itself and not need to import it into ours. Note, the serving app is not necessarily aware of the client app and does not share protocols, app ids, etc. BTW, I am aware of iOS's sandboxing, inter-application communication, and pasteboards.

What is the current state of mobile software development whether hybrid, indigenous, or progressive web application development in this arena (iOS and Android)?

**For example, if we're in Twitter, we'd like to change the color of a tweet from blue to green or insert a 'star' object at a particular spot in the tweet, where pressed will copy it into our own app. Something along those lines.**

Any thoughts on this (iOS and Android) will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if we're in Twitter, we'd like to change the color of a tweet from blue to green or insert a 'star' object at a particular spot in the tweet, where pressed will copy it into our own app. Something along those lines.

I cannot speak for iOS. On Android, what you want has never been possible, for obvious security reasons. An app has no means of directly modifying the UI of another app, except perhaps on rooted devices (where ordinary security restrictions can be bypassed) or on custom ROMs (where you can build in security weaknesses that meet your needs).

Comment: Thanks.  Any thoughts on how Lastpass is able to seemingly circumvent this (seemingly using accessibility) and detect and insert credentials in the UID/PWD fields? In other words, what's special about these fields and can't it be extended to manipulate other areas of an app?

Comment: @MoMo: " Any thoughts on how Lastpass is able to seemingly circumvent this (seemingly using accessibility) and detect and insert credentials in the UID/PWD fields?" -- that's not what you were asking to do. "what's special about these fields" -- they are fields (i.e., `EditText` widgets). Accessibility only allows limited input for widgets that are specifically written to support accessibility events to control their input. "can't it be extended to manipulate other areas of an app?" -- via your own customized version of the Android OS? Sure.